# Application Error event in Global asax not firing on extension-less 404 errors

Tags: error-handling, iis-6, http-status-code-404

I'm currently running asp.net webforms .net 3.5 w/ IIS 6.

I've attempted to make a custom error page for all types of errors, and custom handlers based on the type of error and status code, if one exists.

Now, everything is running fine locally on cassini. However, when I deploy it to a development box running IIS6, the 404 errors **do not hit** the application_error event in the global.asax. Instead, it passes through my attempts at error handling and goes directly to IIS's defined custom error page for 404s.

I currently have IIS6 setup with a wildcard to pass everything through the .NET dll, just like cassini is setup.

I'm terribly confused on why this isn't occurring on dev the same way it is locally. Can anyone please chime in and help? Thanks in advance.

p.s.

Here's my web config. I'm not using the build-in error handling except to turn my handling on/off, and to catch any errors that fall through my error handling:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/error.htm" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the 404 handler in the IIS to point to an aspx file **that does not exist**. This will trigger Application_Error for all 404s.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll check into this as soon as I have a free moment.

Comment: @letsgetsilly - did you have a free moment to confirm this answer?